# Virtual destructor on IUknown Derived interfaces

Tags: c++, c++11, com

I have been doing some code learning by reading some existing code. I know the importance of having a virtual destructors on Interfaces which are non com types. I mean which do not derive from IUnkown or IInspectable.

However, I am not able to understand why it is not required to have a virtual destructor on a COM interface.

I have my interface defined like this

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("0D70D782-809D-403B-AC95-XXXXXX")
IMyInterface : IUnknown
{
    public:
      virtual bool method1() = 0;
      virtual int method2() = 0;
}
```

And at the same time I have another interface which doesnt derive from IUnkown like this

```
    class ISampleLogic
    {
      public:
         virtual ~ISampleLogic() {};
         //some more methods

    }
```

Why there is no virtual destructor for first interface?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally, it is OK for an "interface" to not have a virtual destructor if you have no intention of calling delete on the interface. Although, if that is the case it [is probably good practice](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) to have a protected destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IUnknown` has a method called `Release()`. Its job is to decrement the object's *reference count* and destroy the object if that reference count drops to zero. So it acts as the destructor; and an explicit destructor is therefore not required.

If you have an `IUnknown` pointer (say `IUnknown* punk`), you shouldn't `delete` it, but call `Release()` instead (`punk->Release()`). That's because other processes may have a reference count on the object.

It's down to the *implementation* of the interface to ensure that the entire object is deleted. That implementation may well contain classes with virtual destructors, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but punk->Release() internally calls a delete on itself (punk). (delete this). At this point also we are calling delete and can fall in the same problem of delete called on Non com interfaces. Does it mean that in non com interfaces delete is called on the interface reference and in com interfaces delete is called on the concrete class reference? hence we don't fall in this problem. Sorry just trying to clear this in my head.

Comment: "punk->Release() internally calls a delete on itself (punk). (delete this)". Do you know that for sure? What about COM objects that are written in languages other than C++?

Comment: Well its implementation and language dependent, but eventually it will be something like delete myself, in respective languages. Thats why I said that.

Answer (score 4):

Your first code snippet defines an interface, and the other one defines a class which is not an interface (even though you refer to it as "another interface").

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50h7kwtb.aspx):

> A Visual C++ interface can be defined as follows:
>
> - Can inherit from zero or more base interfaces.
> - Cannot inherit from a base class.
> - Can only contain public, pure virtual methods.
> - **Cannot contain constructors, destructors, or operators.**
> - Cannot contain static methods.
> - Cannot contain data members; properties are allowed.

Long story short, interfaces don't need and are not allowed to have virtual destructors. It is the hosting implementation who is responsible for construction and destruction, COM interface definition is a contract on set of methods and their syntax.

Comment: I agree, and I would add that one should define the interface with either IDL or VC++ extended COM keywords.